# Neo4j search for second shortest path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We know that we can get the shortest path between nodes by the following statement

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((a)-[*]->(b))
```

Is there any way to search for the second shortest path without exhaustive search?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to specify something like *second shortest path* via `shortestPath()` or `allShortestPaths()`. However: You could search for all paths, ordered by path length, and just limit the depth and number of items returned. For example:

```
MATCH p =(a)-[*2..5]-(b)
RETURN p, length(p)
order by length(p)
LIMIT 5;
```

You'd have to fine-tune this based on your knowledge of the domain (such as min # and max # of relationship hops). And you can further optimize with the addition of labels and relationship types.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the shortest path in a subquery first and then find the paths that are longer than the shorter path.

```
CALL
{MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[*]->(b))
RETURN length(p) as `shortPathLength`}
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[*]->(b))
WHERE length(p) > `shortPathLength`
RETURN p
```

Using SKIP or LIMIT and hardcoding a number to skip the first shortest path is likely to fetch undesired results in your use case  if there are multiple shortest paths with the smallest number of hops.